# Jenkins for running a background Script?

Tags: python, rest, jenkins, cron, monitoring

I wrote a python script to send Data from a local DB via REST to Kafka.
**My goal:** I would like this script to run indefinitely, by either restarting in set intervals (i.e. every 5min) or whenever the DB gets new entries. I assume the set Intervals thing would be good enough, easier and safer. 
Someone suggested to me to either run it via a cronjob and use a monitoring tool or do it using jenkins (which he considered better).

**My Setting:** I am not a DevOps engineer, and would like to know about the possibilities and risks setting this Script up. It would be no trouble to recreate the Script in Java if this improves the situation.

**My Question:** I did try to learn what jenkins is about and i think i understood the CI and CD part. But i don't see how this could help me with my goal. Can someone elaborate on this with some experience on this topic?
If you would suggest a cronjob, what are common methods or tools to monitor such a case? I think the main risks are, failing to send the data due to connection issues on the local machine to REST or the local DB or not beieng started properly at the specified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs can be scheduled at regular intervals in Jenkins just like with cron, in fact it uses the same syntax. What's nice about scheduling the job via Jenkins, is that it's very easy to have it send an email if the job exits with a non-zero return code. I've moved all of my cron jobs into Jenkins and it's working well. So by running it via Jenkins you're covering the execution side and the monitoring side at the same time.